# Inheritance in Java, how to design clasess without own attributes

Tags: java, oop, uml

I am not sure how to represent a model in Java which include inheritance. I have three classes which inherit  from a super class, but one of them doesn't have different attributes neither methods than super class, for example:

```
public class Animal{
  public int a;
  public int b;
  public int c;
}

public class Cat extends Animal (){
  public int d;
  public int e;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public int f;
  public int g;
}

public class Cow extends Animal {
//it doesn't have different attributes or methods than Animal
}
```

(Attributes and classes above are only examples) 
How should I design that? Is it correct to have a class wich only extends from a super class without having its own attributes? or should I omit Cow class and instantiate it from Animal? Thank you!

Comment: this is more a matter of taste. i would do what makes the code as easy to read. propably creating the cow class also. variables or methods might be added later when the cow species evolves

Comment: Cow certainly is an Animal, nothing should stop Cow from extending Animal.

Comment: `Animal` should be an `abstract class` (if it truly makes sense to provide fields) or `interface` (if it only needs to provide methods without implementations).

Answer (score 3):

Animal class is better to be an **abstract** class with common methods that all animals share.
then you can create a class Cow extend the abstract class so that you can call those common method( e.g. eat and drink and specify methods for cow such as moo()

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to create a Cow class that extends Animal even though it doesn't add any attributes.  A Cow is still a type of animal even if it doesn't add any behavior or data to the Animal class that is specific to being a Cow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create a new class representing a `Cow` object just the same. Consider a few months from now you would like to add some new behaviour... without the `Cow` class you would need to rewrite certain sections of your code... sections you most likely had already tested.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to create a Cow class as @Chris said, plus imagine if you had a method to feed the animals you method would look something like this:

```
public void feedAnimal(Animal animal);
```

now if you wouldn't extend cow to class Animal you would have to create a second method to feed the cow:

```
public void feedCow(Cow cow);
```

even tough it's an animal

Answer (score 0):

If you have other Animals other than Cat, Dog and Cow and you use objects for those Animals by instantiating the Animal class then there is no point for another Cow class that does not bring anything new (not new fields, no new methods, no overridden methods).

On the other hand you only have Animals of type Cat, Dog and Cow then you should make your Animal class an abstract one (or an interface for greater flexibility).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if your `Cow` class is identical to `Animal` there's something wrong in your design.

I mean, instead of extending an `Animal` class, maybe you need a `BasicAnimal` class and several extending classes only when you actually need to add features.

Or an alternative could be to transform yor `Animal` class to an interface (or an abstract class) and implement/extend it.

In the abstract class you should implement only common methods. But if you find that the behavior of `Cow` is the same of `Animal` could be better to go the `BasicAnimal` way...

Answer (score 0):

Three reasons why you should not implement "cow" in class animal:

1. The word animal is itself an abstraction (the class should be abstract, impossible to make a new).
2. When you define a class, you define a type (cow is a concrete type even without no attributes or method). You can also use "instance of" to disambiguate if necessary
3. Last and most important, when you use inheritance, you should always comply with the principle of substitution (all elements that refer to "Animal", should work replacing "Animal" by "cat", "dog" or "Cow")